# ¿Cómo embeber una base de datos Neodatis u otra en un programa desarrollado en java?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, embebido, neodatis

Mi aplicación desarrollada en java crea una base de datos Neodatis para las operaciones CRUD. Estoy usando Netbeans como IDE y dicha base de datos se crea en una carpeta llamada bds dentro de src. Hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema viene al ejecutar la aplicación ya compilada, es decir ejecuto el "aplicacion.jar" de la carpeta dist. Me crea una subcarpeta bds con la base de datos dentro y lo que yo quiero es que la base de datos se integre **dentro de la aplicación**, o dicho de otro modo, que no cree la carpeta bds y la base de datos no sea visible.

¿Como podría hacerlo?
¿En caso de no ser posible, que tipo de base de datos me permitiría embeberla en la aplicación?

Comment: Por "dentro de la aplicación" te refieres a "dentro del jar"?

Comment: Así es @SJuan76 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ni es habitual, ni es recomendable incluir una Base de Datos dentro de la aplicación sea un EXE, un JAR, o cualquier otro tipo de fichero.

Una acción como esta tiene muchos inconvenientes y muy poco ventajas por no decir ninguna (si hay alguna que no conozcamos, por favor coméntanosla).

Aunque lo hicieras (que técnicamente se puede), deberías descomprimir la Base de Datos "en algún sitio" para trabajar con ella (en cuyo momento volvería a ser visible) como en el caso inicial que comentas. No sólo eso, sino que una vez que finalizaras tu aplicación y la Base de Datos hubiera sufrido cambios, no tendrías qué hacer con ella. ¿Volver a "meterla" en el EXE? ¿Dejarla ahí?

Comment: En el caso de que siguiera haciéndola externa, ¿cómo podría evitar que alguien con un pendrive o remotamente copiase esa base de datos y se la llevase?

Comment: Tienes que mirar las opciones que te da la Base de Datos en cuanto a seguridad, encriptación, contraseñas,...  Dependerá de la opción que hayas escogido o escojas.

Comment: Neodatis permite establecer un usuario y una contraseña, pero no parece que sirva de mucho, pues si tienes acceso al archivo que crea puedes ver los datos guardados al abrirlo con notepad++, por ejemplo. Aunque no dice a que pertenecen esos datos es un riesgo enorme.

Comment: Siempre puedes encriptar manualmente un dato sensible, antes de guardarlo en la Base de Datos y desencriptarlo al recuperarlo. Esto es viable para datos puntuales. Si es a nivel más amplio de todos los datos no tiene sentido hacerlo manualmente y deberías pensar en otra opción con mejores características en seguridad.

Comment: Si, eso ya lo había tenido en cuenta. De hecho, encripto absolutamente todos los datos con la máxima seguridad. Pero quiero aumentar esa seguridad evitando que la base de datos sea robada o visualizada manualmente. Podría incluso plantearme cambiar de tipo de base de datos si así consigo dicho objetivo.

Comment: Si encriptas los datos y lo haces de forma adecuada, al abrir la Base de Datos con el notepad, como comentas, no debería verse nada.

Comment: Hasta cierto punto eso es cierto. Se verían los datos encriptados. No obstante, podría alguien podría cortar el archivo y llevárselo en un pendrive, o peor, borrarlos, dejando al usuario sin los datos. Recordemos a esos usuarios iluminados que borran carpetas críticas del sistema por que les ocupa espacio.

Comment: Si tienes acceso a copiar el fichero y borrarlo, también puedes borrar el fichero de la aplicación y tienes el mismo problema, te quedas sin aplicación. En ese caso tendrías que mirar de restringir quien tiene acceso a la localización del programa, pero eso ya entra en la seguridad del sistema.

Comment: Entonces creo que he llegado a un punto sin salida. la única opción menos mala será crearla fuera, encriptada y oculta.

Comment: Si quieres cualquier clase de seguridad, la respuesta es siempre la misma. Pon la BD en un servidor y accede remotamente. Las estaciones de cliente son inseguras por definición.